# Styling Text inside Android TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, each Target Text has a mix of numbers and strings. I want the numbers to be highlighted in Bold and string to be italicised. For e.g.

*You have reached* **25%** *of your goal.* **30** *more days to achieve target*

Is there an easier way to do it than create 5 separate textviews for this - 3 for string and 2 for number. Managing layout of 5 textboxes for each target is becoming a nightmare in my layout. I have 9 such rows leading to potentially 45 textviews in one layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<i>` and `<b>` html tags within your string, like this:

```
<string name="my_string"><i>You have reached</i> <b>25%</b> <i>of your goal.</i> <b>30</b> <i>more days to achieve target</i></string>
```

You can read more here, under the **Styling with HTML markup** section: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example,

For Kotlin

```
textView.text = Html.fromHtml("<b>Hello</b> <i>World</i>")
```

For Java

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Hello</b> <i>World</i>"))
```